# Python: Matplotlib legend with custom labelspacing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that in Python's matlplotlib legend function we can adjust the spacing between the labels using "labelspacing", for example:

```
lgd = ax.legend(..., labelspacing=2)
```

but can I have a more custom spacing between labels where for example the space between the first two labels is *2* and between the 2nd and 3rd label is *3*, and so on?

Doing so would allow me to line up the labels with the lines in my plot nicely (outside the plot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's no easy way to do this, as `plt.legend` uses a `VPacker` to manage the entries in the legend: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/legend.py#L713

`VPacker` only supports a single `sep` for all entries:
http://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.VPacker

Have you thought about drawing the legend manually?
(E.g. drawing a white box with `patches.Rectangle` and the text with `plt.text`)
That would probably also make it much easier to align the items with the contents of your plot.
For example, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

rect = patches.Rectangle((0.7, 0.35), 0.2, 0.3, facecolor='white')
plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
plt.text(0.75, 0.58, 'my')
plt.text(0.75, 0.5, 'custom')
plt.text(0.75, 0.42, 'legend')
```

[image: custom legend]

Comment: you convinced me that's the way to do this.